# How do I change the compiler and CXX_FLAGS for CMAKE of a C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, devpartner

I'm currently working on an unmanaged Windows C++ application.

I'm new to the world of CMAKE and C++.

I'm also new to the world of this current unmanaged C++ application.

I'm trying to integrate DevPartner into my build to instrument the build for memory errors and runtime errors.

In order to build for instrumentation, I need to change to using the DevPartner compiler (`nmcl.exe`).

Additionally, I need to add compiler settings to the existing `CXX_FLAGS` for instrumentation.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

For VS releases 2008 and earlier.... (Except VS6 it uses msdev)

Well digging more into cmake I will say this someone with more knowledge will be able to take this and run with it.

I did find that the CL and LINK commands really do nothing since this just kicks off Devenv for VS2003 to 2008 and MSBuild for VS2010. Changing CL to NMCL will not matter since MSBuild uses the targets files which is why my other answer needs the user files modified. And why we need to use another tool here.

Devenv called with  /Build internally uses the project files to know what source files need to be built. It will then call createprocess internally to spawn CL and LINK as needed. This is why changing CL to NMCL in the cmake files is useless.

Luckily we have another tool that can be used here....

We need to change 
//make program
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Micro Focus/NMShared/CTI/11.1/NMdevenv.EXE

and 
CMAKE_BUILD_TOOL:INTERNAL=e:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.com

to C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Micro Focus/NMShared/CTI/11.1/NMdevenv.EXE

Now this is where someone with a little more knowledge is needed. We also need to pass the type of instrumentation to nmdevenv as the 1st parameters.

I believe it can be done something like this

set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} " /nmon")

One other issue here is that we need devenv to be in the path as well so the Path env variable will need to be set correctly as well. This can be done by running the correct vscvars bat file.

Hope this helps and if you are using vs2008 and previous please add the steps needed to what I started here. I am sure it will help other users in the long run. If I get some more time to investigate this I will find the way to do it.

***Edit***
Well I did manage to  get this working with VS2008. I did have to make a change to our nmdevenv wrapper as cmake was trashing our SearchPath functionality.

Here is what I did. 
Replaced the make program as above
Ran VCVars32
Ran cmake --build mytestproj
Ran the program under BounsChecker

Now I switched to pass in /nmtxon for performance profiling
This had me stumped for a bit as it kept compiling for Error Detection

And that is when I found this in the converted project files

```
        <Tool
            Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
            AdditionalOptions=" /NMbcon /Zm1000"
```

Changed that to

and all is well. I had my performance compiled option.

So I went back and modified this line in the CMakeCache.txt file opened the GUI, configue, generate 
//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING= /NMbcon /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /Zm1000 /EHsc /GR

Then the project was switched back to use /NMbcon. So that is the correct spot to put the switch if you want to compile all with us. Otherwise use the appropriate Debug or release line.

---

portion of Cmake output
Notice Instrumenting in the output

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.30729.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
New Command line nmcl.exe /NMtxon  @e:\cust\Test3\Test\Test.dir\Debug\RSP0000011
2568792.rsp /nologo /errorReport:queue
1>Test3.cpp
1>Instrumenting ..\Test3\Test3.cpp
1>Compiling manifest to resources...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>Linking...
```

---

In summary

Use Cmake to generate the CMakeCache.txt and directories
Modify CmakeCahe 
    Use NMDevenv as the MAKE program
    Add /NMon switch to the flags
run CmakeGui and generate again

Run VCVars32
Run cmake --build  file

Run the program under devpartner

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for digging into this. I'm currently looking at your postings on this topic. To be clear, I should be following the changes you've indicated in your last post? I just want to be sure. I've been looking at the various CMAKE_CXX_XXXXXXX settings and trying to make the appropriate changes which would get the actual project makefiles regenerated with the correct compiler and flags. No luck so far. Thanks,

Comment: Which version of visual Studio are you using? If VS2008 or previous then yes the last post if VS2010 then the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using?  That makes a fair amount of difference, as how the instrumentation is managed has changed over the years . . . not so much by version of DevPartner as by version of Visual Studio.

Comment: I defer everything to my co-worker, Mark.  He specializes (as much as any of us specialize in any particular part of the product) in the compiler instrumentation part of the product.  My specialty is the client side of BoundsChecker, which attaches itself like an overgrown virus to the executable under test.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure for a cmake file but this is from an old VS 6 makefile modified for Devpartner. Perhaps you can post a relevant section of the makefile for me to look at.

/nmbcon is a compile flag that says use BC instrumentation /nmtxon would be used for coverage analysis

CPP=cl.exe

CPP_PROJ=/nologo /MD /W3 /Gm /GX /Zi /Od /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_AFXDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D "_AFXEXT" /Fp"$(INTDIR)\main.pch" /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fo"$(INTDIR)\" /Fd"..\bin\Debug\MAIN.pdb" /FD /GZ /c

Would become

CPP=nmcl.exe

CPP_PROJ= /nmbcon /nologo /MD /W3 /Gm /GX /Zi /Od /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_AFXDLL" /D "_MBCS" /D "_AFXEXT" /Fp"$(INTDIR)\main.pch" /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fo"$(INTDIR)\" /Fd"..\bin\Debug\MAIN.pdb" /FD /GZ /c

Oh and the other poster is correct things have greatly changed by version of Visual Studio. VS2010 changed the build process to use MSBuild this caused us to completely modify the way we intercept and instterument for VS2010 and 2012.

****EDIT***

Well I did download and go through the *pain* of Cmake internship this morning. For VS2010 this seems to be a pretty simple modification just like would be needed for one of our users using MSBuild from the command line.

In the out dir "Where to build the binaries" after the first build there will be .vcxproj.user files. This is where you need to add the flags for instrumentation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <DevPartner_IsInstrumented>1</DevPartner_IsInstrumented>
    <DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> /NMbcOn</DevPartner_Instrumented_Type>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This can be a repeating section for each  
that you wish to build.

The next key DevPartner_IsInstrumented tells us to instrument (1) or not (0).
The last key DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> is what type to instrumetnt /nmbcon (Boundschecker) /nmtxon (Performance or Coverage) or both keys passed.

So it could look like

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <DevPartner_IsInstrumented>1</DevPartner_IsInstrumented>
    <DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> /NMbcOn</DevPartner_Instrumented_Type>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <DevPartner_IsInstrumented>0</DevPartner_IsInstrumented>
    <DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> /NMbcOn</DevPartner_Instrumented_Type>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DevPartner_IsInstrumented>0</DevPartner_IsInstrumented>
    <DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> /NMbcOn</DevPartner_Instrumented_Type>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <DevPartner_IsInstrumented>1</DevPartner_IsInstrumented>
    <DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> /NtxcOn</DevPartner_Instrumented_Type>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

which would be Boundschecker for Debug win32, nothing for Release win32, nothing for debug x64 and Performance / Coverage for release x64

If IsInstrumented 0 whatever is in the type will not matter as it will not be passed.

FYI if you open the solution in VS2010 and turn instrumentation on this will be added to the vcxproj.user files for you. And the instrumentation settings are by project / config as well.

If not using VS2010 my note below might be correct for those versions.

For full disclosure I am the lead developer on the instrumentation engine for DevPartner.

Comment: OK. So selecting the project to be instrumented from DevPartner->Instrumentation Manager has no effect on  the vcxproj.user file. In fact, if I select the project to be instrumented from the "Check projects to be instrumented" section in the dialog, click OK and then reopen the Instrumentation Manager Dialog, those checked boxes were not persisted.

Comment: I will attempt to make the changes by hand directly to the project to the vxproj.user file. I'm not clear on how this going to cause the nmcl compiler and associated flags to be set.

Comment: Well that is a some of the beauty of MSBuild. in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\ImportBefore you will see a few files in the targets file it shows that it will change the "CLCompileTool" if the one flag is set to "1". It will append the other flag as a compile switch. There is another set of these files in the X64 directory as well. As these are import before they are pulled into the build process before compile time by the targets in the directory above this. Believe me this was very fun to figure out how to integrate into MSBuild in the first place.

Comment: Cool. I looked in the ImportBefore directory and see what you mean.  However I apologize, I'm still not quite clear on what I need to do here. Should I go and edit all the .vcxproj.user files by hand so that they contain:     <DevPartner_IsInstrumented>1</DevPartner_IsInstrumented> 
<DevPartner_Instrumented_Type> /NMbcOn</DevPartner_Instrumented_Type>  directly? I guess this would make sense, since trying to turn on instrumentation directly in VS2010 through the DevPartner Instrumentation dialog has no effect. Comments? Thanks,JB

Comment: Yes you would need to or you could turn it on in VS2010 and then copy those vcxproj.user files from the true project directories into the "Where to build the binaries" directory (where the ALL_BUILD and CMakeCache.txt files are located) of your cmake project. I am sure you could set this up in cmake to do the copy for you too. But again I am a cmake newbie as well.